# Computation of Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am studying a linear algebra course and there's a problem with the calculation of the eigenvalues of a matrix. It's probably due to my own error, due to a wrong method or unsound algebraic concepts. The thing is , I keep goofing up the characteristic polynomial for the matrix an end up with wrong eigenvalues. Is there a way to simplify the calculation? I used the general method for expanding the determinant along a particular column or row.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Where is the actual problem? Are you looking for general guidance only? Regards

Answer (score 0):

First off, posting the actual question is probably going to be more helpful for us.

Secondly, I usually simplify the calculation of determinant by doing some elementary row operations and getting some zeroes on a row or column and then expand along said row or column.

Perhaps the matrix is incorrect? It is supposed to be $(\lambda I_n-A)$, where $A$ is the matrix.

Also, it might be possible that in your calculation of the determinant, you might have forgot to incorporate the cofactor: $(-1)^{i+j}$.